# Docker Image Build Fails with "Permission denied" Errors on macOS [Payara/micro:5.2021.9]

Tags: docker, macos, dockerfile, docker-image, payara-micro

I'm encountering an issue while building a Docker image using the payara/micro:5.2021.9 base image on macOS Ventura 13.5 with Docker v24.0.7 and Docker Desktop v4.26.1.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM payara/micro:5.2021.9

USER root

RUN apk update
```

Build Command:

```
docker build -t test -f Dockerfile . && docker run -it test
```

Error Message:

```
[+] Building 1.0s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                   docker:desktop-linux
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                               0.0s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 2.08kB                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/payara/micro:5.2021.9                                                                                                                                   0.6s
=> CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/payara/micro:5.2021.9@sha256:1b163a9a7c4277173b4be460bba1e09d8402183a91777d16d676655c10410b00                                                                      0.0s
=> ERROR [2/2] RUN apk update                                                                                                                                                                     0.5s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [2/2] RUN apk update:                                                                                                                                                                                
0.119 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                     
0.254 140737488350024:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:                                                               
0.255 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: Permission denied                                                                                                                        
0.255 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory                                                                                                     
0.255 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.333 140737488350024:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:
0.340 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: Permission denied
0.340 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: No such file or directory
0.341 fetch https://repos.azul.com/zulu/alpine/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.452 140737488350024:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1914:
0.453 ERROR: https://repos.azul.com/zulu/alpine: Permission denied
0.453 WARNING: Ignoring https://repos.azul.com/zulu/alpine: No such file or directory
0.453 3 errors; 34 distinct packages available
------
Dockerfile:9
--------------------
  7 |     USER root
  8 |     
  9 | >>> RUN apk update
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 3

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/p1qsaohius4p99y1kay7shc5l
```

I'm receiving three "Permission denied" errors when trying to update the package list within the container. Could someone help me understand the cause of these errors and suggest potential solutions?

### Update 1

I tried to modify the docker image in this way in order to test its functioning by disabling the ssl verification:

```
FROM payara/micro:5.2021.9

USER root

RUN apk --no-cache --update add --virtual build-dependencies --allow-untrusted
RUN apk update
```

In this case the first RUN is executed successfully. The second one always generates the same error.

### Update 2

I'm starting to think that maybe the problem is with the Alpine distribution as I tried to create the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine
RUN apk update
```

I ran it with the following command:

```
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t test -f Dockerfile . && docker run -it test
```

and I got the following output:

```
[+] Building 1.6s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                      docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.18kB                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine                                                                                                               1.2s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine@sha256:05973053a0aa55d3b4bcaf194d98568bdb3fbea47ad3783a0d923b43e0f4c77a                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN apk update                                                                                                                                                        0.4s
------                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [2/2] RUN apk update:                                                                                                                                                                   
0.127 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.270 140737488350024:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
0.272 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: Permission denied
0.272 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory
0.272 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.343 140737488350024:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1919:
0.344 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: Permission denied
0.344 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: No such file or directory
0.344 2 errors; 17 distinct packages available
------
Dockerfile:14
--------------------
  12 |     
  13 |     FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine
  14 | >>> RUN apk update
  15 |     
  16 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/xzbikn2f9xkr04cdb3w40a808
```

However, if I try to use the debian distribution:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8
RUN apt update
```

The problem is resolved and the container is initialized correctly. At this point, how can I create a docker image in debian with Payara micro 5.2021.9?

Comment: This looks likes an ssl verification error, can you maybe try disable the verification and try to rebuild to confirm my claim ?

```RUN apk --no-cache --update add --virtual build-dependencies --allow-untrusted
```

Alternatively, can we use a different alpine base image eg azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11-jre

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the test you suggested and actually this new RUN runs correctly (see Update 1 in the question). I also tried replacing payara/micro:5.2021.9 with azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11-jre but nothing changed.